# Jasmine: How to test a fetch in a fetch?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am looking to test nested fetches. So far I can test the result of the first fetch but can't access the other one. I have tried nesting the next fetch call in the first but that does not seem to work. The second SpyOn function call creates a jasmine errors saying I can't have multiple spys for the same function.

Jasmine test

```
  let response = new Response(
  JSON.stringify({
    test: "test",
  })
);

// creating a fetch spy
spyOn(window, "fetch").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(response));

// make call to fetch
callFirstFetch().then((result) => {
  expect(window.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/test");

  spyOn(window, "fetch").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(response));

  done();
});
```

and the nested fetch code looks like

```
function firstFetch(() => {
   return fetch("/test")
        .then(response => { 
                           response.json();
                           return secondFetch(); 
        })
});

function secondFetch(() => {
   return fetch("/test2")
        .then(response => { 
                           response.json();
                           console.log('done');
        })
});
 
firstFetch();
```

Comment: What's wrong with `expect(window.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/test"); expect(window.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/test2");` or count the # calls to `fetch`?

Comment: Why would you want to test mocked return data from an API that is internal. It is a waste of time/resources testing the internals.

Answer (score 6):

This is how you can mock your fetch api call:

```
const okResponse = new Response(JSON.stringify({}), { status: 200, statusText: 'OK', });
spyOn(window, 'fetch').and.resolveTo(okResponse);
```

And then test it like this:

```
expect(window.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(requestUrl, options);
```

Comment: This worked for me. Only issue is that it doesn't behave nice if it's in a fakeAsync call. Using a real async helped fix it.